# What would be the AMP Cache status if the backend throws 504

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

Let's say I have a valid AMP Cache document hosted at google's CDN. Based on my understanding, When a user fetches a cached document, google displays the cached version, goes and fetches the latest document from my server and updates the cache for new user.
**But what would happen if my server throws a 504 error?** Will google discard the cache and show no amp page or keep the cache intact until it receives a response from server?

Comment: Based from this [documentation](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/using_the_google_amp_cache/), if an URL returns a `5XX` server errors, the AMP Cache will return a `404` status. Also as stated in this [thread](http://www.knowamp.com/question/Vmtab2QxVnNRbEpRVkRBOQ==/Google-AMP-Cache-Redirect--Error-Handling), the AMP Cache follows redirects when resolving AMP URLs. For example, if an URL redirects to another AMP URL, then the AMP Cache will return the content of the resolved redirect for the original URL.

Comment: That would mean that a cache returning 404 status basically means that the document doesn't exist in amp format and won't be shown as an amp version in google search result. Right?